# Javascript populate a section of the page on button click with image and text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dynamic webpage that has buttons to filter products based on category's, I have managed to get it to repopulate the page with text using this code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<main>Hello World</main>";
}
</script>
```

However I also need it to load a image and place it to the left within the  tag, I have tried using the src method:

```
("image").src ="image.gif";
```

but I had no luck with it, and after searching for quite some time I decided to ask here, thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: you have two ways of doing that: the first is by adding the <img> html to the demo element, and the second is to create ad <img> object via js and then append it to the demo element

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the raw way:

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<main> " +
                                                " <img src='myImg.jpg' class='myClass'> " +
                                                " <span class='myClass2'>Hello World</span> "+ 
                                                "</main>";
```

and the css that goes with it to make everything float to the left

```
    .myClass {
        float:left;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }

    .myCLass2 {
        float:left;
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
    }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: you're welcome! don't forget to mark this answer if it solved ur problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript approach would be like this...

HTML:

```
<button onclick='populate()'>Click Me!</button>
<div id="populateMe"></div>
```

JS:

```
function populate() {
    var div = document.getElementById("populateMe");
    var text = "..."
    var imgSrc= "..."
    div.innerHTML = "<div>" + text + "</div><img id="image" src='" + imgSrc + "' />"
}
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could use is "setAttribute" method which is generic and should let you set src value.

Please have a look at this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/samador/c14w4odv/13/embedded/result/) I created for you:

```js
hideImg = function (imgId){
        var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
    
    if (img){
        
        var newStyle = img.getAttribute("style").replace("display: block", "display: none");
        img.setAttribute("style", newStyle);
    }
}

showImg = function (imgId, imgSrc){
    
    var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
    
    if (img){
        
        if (imgSrc)
            img.setAttribute("src", imgSrc);
        
        var newStyle = img.getAttribute("style").replace("display: none", "display: block");
        img.setAttribute("style", newStyle);
    }
}

isVisible = function(imgId) {
    
    var itIs = true;
    var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
    
    if (img) {
        
        if (img.getAttribute("style").indexOf("display: none") >= 0)
          itIs = false;    
    }
    else {
        itIs = false;
    }
    
    return itIs;
}

toggleImg = function () {
    
    if (!isVisible("myimg"))
        showImg("myimg", "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png");
    else
        hideImg("myimg");
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(70, 121, 189)">
    
    <img id="myimg" style="display: none"/>
    
    <button onclick="toggleImg()">Toggle image</button>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you.
Even though, if you plan to handle DOM elements quite often it will worth to spent some time to learn jQuery.